# SIM808 Not Able To Send Sms On Roaming

Tags: sms, gsm, gprs, roaming

I am using sim808 module to send sms from my device. Everything works fine when I use a local sim card (within the same circle, I'm based out of India).

However the sms are not coming through when using a roaming sim card. The sms show as sent from the sim808 side but never reach the destination.

For example, my sms gateway is based out of New Delhi. When I use a Delhi sim card all is good. However when I use a sim card from bangalore the issue happens.

The sim card is fine as I can send sms through the same sim card using my phone.

Any insight on what could be going on here would be great. Thanks!

Comment: First check if you have SMSC number properly entered on SIM card, Also note that many SMS providers use SMS hubs, which may block SMS (or some other issues)

Comment: @Marvin yes I checked with the SMSC command and the number is configured. Though I do not know of that is the right number for roaming. I would assume that in roaming you would need to use the locations local SMSC number but how do I find that? On cellphone, the provider pushes you roaming settings but how would that work on sim808?

Comment: The SMSC number is always a number defined by the operator whose SIM card belong. All other SMSC numbers will not work. But you must use international format of that number to work anywhere (e.g. +...... or 00....)

Comment: @Marvin understood. But when the sim card is in roaming, does the SMSC number change?

Comment: It does not change.